# Remove Spacing or Padding below Android Tabbed Activity (Action Bar Tabs)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

I just created a default "Tabbed Activity - Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager)"
using AndroidStudio

My Question is that - how do I remove the Spacing/Padding on the top while scrolling, but keep the Spacing/Padding at the begining.

Thank You

[image: Screenshot]

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="...."></TextView>

</ScrollView>
```

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [arpit]

figured it out
Just added some id's

Now Working

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/v1"
            android:text="..."></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
```

I hope i correctly understood what you're trying.

Comment: I already tried that, plz check image, not working like i want it to. http://postimg.org/image/q0vgqn9a5/

Answer (score 0):

Just modify XML:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="...."></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open res/values/dimens.xml and change the vertical margin there

```
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

and horizontal too if you wish:

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
```